# merge google documents spreadsheets add on

Tags: merge, google-drive-api, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

I'm trying to merge a few documents with the add-on "merge google documents spreadsheets". I followed the steps here (https://appsthatdeliver.com/app-tutorials/google-docs/merge-combine-google-docs/) and the add-on is successfully installed to my drive (I can see it in the "open with" for any document in my drive).

There comes the issue :
When I choose 2 google docs and open those with the "Merge google documents", the new page opens but "0 added".
I then tried choosing a google doc or a folder from this new page but it doesn't work : nothing changes with the "0 added", visually too.

Well, I hope you have an idea there...
Alix B